# Jquery select which children to show

Tags: jquery, dom, children

I have following html

```
<div class="foo">
    <a href="" class="bar1">Bar1</a>
    <a href="" class="bar2">Bar2</a>
</div>
```

let's say .foo is hide in default, then I just want to show .foo and his child .bar1. How to do this in jquery?

I have this in my jquery

```
$('#' + id).children(".foo //anything I can do here to select ONLY bar1 to show? ").show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would hide all children and just show `bar1`. See below,

```
var $foo = $('.foo');    //cache foo
$foo.children().hide();  //hide all foo's children
$foo.show();             //show foo
$foo.find('.bar1').show();  //show bar1
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work.

```
$('#' + id).find(".foo .bar1").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".foo").show();
$(".foo").children(".bar1").show();

$(".foo").children("not:(.bar1)").hide();//if not hidden
```

Answer (score 0):

u can type

```
$('.foo').toggle();
```

to display or hide the foo div container.

to select the bar 1 u can select `$('.foo > .bar1').somefunction()` or `$('.foo').children('.bar1').somefunction();`

there are so many different ways to select your elements... u can also use `.hide()` or `.show()` to manage if your element is hidden or not

always a nice link btw: http://api.jquery.com/